# when click on button that table is show as model popup and same table print in another component

Tags: html, css, angular

when I click on submit button that table is shown as a model popup and the same table prints in another component. how to pass data using HTML class name from one component to another

**app.parent.html**

```
<div class="sub">  <a onclick="">Submit</a>
```

**app.child.html**

```
<table>  
  <tr class="rw">
    <th scope="col">Tier</th>
    <th scope="col">Range</th>
    <th scope="col">Rate($)</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="rw">
    <td>1</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="rw">
    <td>2</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Could you show us what you have done so far.

Comment: Be more specific with your question, go back, rephrase it and then rush to ask it.